# How to apply scrollbar-primary to a div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I found this [site for Bootstrap pretty scrollbars](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/scroll/). I tried to apply it to my div but nothing happened :

```
<style>
#collapseVehicules {
  height:250px !important;
}
</style>
<div class="collapse scrollbar-primary" id="collapseVehicules" style="padding-left: 15px;padding-right: 15px;overflow-y: scroll;">
   <table id="list" class="table table-borderless table-striped table-sm" style="margin-bottom: 0px;width:100%;">
     ...
   </table>
</div>
```

So what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the styles in your css. `scrollbar-primary` isn't a bootstrap css class style.
As shown on the page, they created the `scrollbar-primary` css class style.

```css
.scrollbar {
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 65px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.scrollbar-primary::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5; 
}

.scrollbar-primary::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #4285F4; 
}
```